# SQL Merge results from the same SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am new to sql and trying to merge the results into the same column of different rows for the sql queries as below. How can I do so?

```
(select distinct szdoc 
 from proddta.f47047 (nolock) 
 where szvr01 = 'RC12/1810/04,3345' and sznxtr >580
) union
(select distinct szdoc 
 from proddta.f47047 (nolock) 
 where szvr01 = 'RC12/1810/04,3345' and sznxtr >580 
)
```

I am getting this:

```
szdoc
_______
18004932
```

Expected results:

```
szdoc
_______
18004932
_______
18004932
```

Comment: Use : `UNION ALL`

Comment: use union all instead of union

Comment: thanks @YogeshSharma, previously I have tried using union all but it throws me an error. Looks it was a mistake from my side.

Comment: And forget about using hints of any type until you have a solid foundation of tsql and you understand the impact of using any particular hint and you know you need to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`union` removes duplicates.  For this query, you want `union all`:

```
(select distinct szdoc 
 from proddta.f47047 (nolock) 
 where szvr01 = 'RC12/1810/04,3345' and sznxtr >580
) union all
(select distinct szdoc 
 from proddta.f47047 (nolock) 
 where szvr01 = 'RC12/1810/04,3345' and sznxtr >580 
)
```

However, I would strongly recommend using a derived table instead:

```
select szdoc 
from (select distinct szdoc
      from proddta.f47047 f
      where szvr01 = 'RC12/1810/04,3345' and
            sznxtr > 580 
     ) f cross join
     (values (1), (2)) v(n)
```

Comment: thanks @Gordon, previously I have tried using union all but it throws me an error. Looks it was a mistake from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Your `expression` & `where` clause seems same then you can remove `distinct`:

```
select szdoc 
from proddta.f47047 (nolock) 
where szvr01 = 'RC12/1810/04,3345' and sznxtr >580;
```

`DISTINCT` will remove duplicate entry.